# YouTube Data API for Uploading Videos not working in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

i am trying to upload a video to YouTube by using YouTube data API, from my application but unfortunately the API which provided by YouTube developers

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

is not working before three weeks i tested the code and it was working fine but now when i try to finally use it in my application its causing a problem all the code is working fine but when the video uploading process starts it's became loading and loading and the video doesn't uploaded i google it but not find any help. if some one can help me ? here is my code which i am using

```
 private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("G:\\client_secret_783534382593-0cn4gm229raqq97kdu0ghsj9hqfsc5o1.apps.googleusercontent.com.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "ttry";
            video.Snippet.Description = " Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1s", "tag2s" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "publi
            var filePath = "F:\\Dna.MP4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

and i am simply calling it from this action

```
  public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            Run().Wait();

            return View();
        }
```

i wonder that why it is not working ? when i debug it then all the things and parameters are fine even credentials are also fine but at the end the file is not uploading even i am selecting 1 MB file and i also included all the necessary NuGet packages kindly some one help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solve by simply adding some bit of code in Get Function

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact()
{
    await Run();
    return View();
}
```